when I disable the default help option and add it as a custom arg, it says that help is a required argument
I wanted to disable the short option 'h' for help and only keep the long '--help' one, so I did that:
#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(version = "0.1.0")]
#[clap(disable_help_flag = true)]
pub struct Args {
    /// Show this help message
    #[arg(long, action = HelpLong)]
    help: bool,
}

But when I do cargo run without providing the help argument, it errors and says:
`The following required argument was not provided: help'
I even tried to add required = false in the arg macro above the help field, but it doesn't change anything.
I also tried to add default_value_t = false, but if I do this the program displays the help message even if I don't provide the help flag, misteriously.

Either make it an Option<bool> or else specify #[arg(default_value_t)].  See https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/_tutorial/chapter_2/index.html#defaults

Try changing help: bool, to help: Option<bool>

@user459872 Thanks, it works with Option, but I don't understand why since I have other bool arguments that work fine and are not set to required, this problem only comes with the help argument

Have you considered filing an issue at the clap repository? It doesn't seem like this behavior was intended.

It seems that no matter what, the help argument will be required when setting its type to bool, and setting a default value to the argument doesn't work either because no matter what you pass to it, even false, it will trigger the help message, so the only way to make it optional is to wrap its type in an Option like this:
#[arg(long, action = HelpLong)]
help: Option<bool>,

